# Problem with DBRider: NoSuchTableException "the table 'MY_NAME_TABLE' does not exist in schema 'null' "

Tags: dbunit

Maybe it`s will be helpfull information.

When I use framework "database-rider" with my postgresql database for spring-boot application they don`t work properly. 
DBUnit the case-sensitive  and want uppercase table names. 
I solved my problem - disabled the case-sensitive option. Added dbunit.yml file in datasets folder. And set next property:

```
caseInsensitiveStrategy: !!com.github.database.rider.core.api.configuration.Orthography 'LOWERCASE'
properties:
  caseSensitiveTableNames: false
```

Comment: I think you need to enable caseSensitiveTableNames by setting It to true, see this example: https://github.com/database-rider/database-rider/blob/bf8dd53625b7e1195816bacfcfac2b871e152356/rider-core/src/test/java/com/github/database/rider/core/PostgreSQLDatabaseIt.java#L26 and in this case you can have tables in lowercase: https://github.com/database-rider/database-rider/blob/bf8dd53625b7e1195816bacfcfac2b871e152356/rider-core/src/test/java/com/github/database/rider/core/model/lowercase/User.java#L8

Comment: I am try realize this example https://github.com/database-rider/database-rider/blob/bf8dd53625b7e1195816bacfcfac2b871e152356/rider-core/src/test/java/com/github/database/rider/core/PostgreSQLDatabaseIt.java#L26 but it not work.